# How to block port server from http request

Tags: linux, docker, server, webserver, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have Nginx has a reversed proxy to connect client request to docker running container.
The **problem** is you can access container by typing `serverhost.fr:port_number`. I want the client to only access the running container by a specific hostname.
Here my docker-compose.yml file :

```
version: '3'
services:
    api:
        image: username/backendimgage:latest
        ports:
            - "8081:8000"
        restart: always
    front:
        depends_on:
            - api
        image: username/frontendimage:latest
        ports:
            - "8080:36073"
        restart: always
```

I've tried to block with ufw, it breaks everything.
I've tried to send a 401 code on Nginx using if statement like

```
if ( $host = serverhost.fr:port_number ){ return 401; }
```

OR

```
if ( $host ~* portnumber ){ return 401; }
```

But it doesn't work. I don't have a big ops background so I'm kind of lost.

Comment: How are you running the two containers?  Can you provide a [mcve] showing both containers' setup?  You don't need a `docker run -p` or Docker Compose `ports:` option to make inter-container connections and the easiest answer might be to remove that setting for the back-end.

Comment: I edit my question to show the dokcer-compose file. I don't see how I can link my reversed proxy to a container without running this container on a port of my server. I will do some google on that point. Just to be clear, my Nginx server isn't running inside a container

Comment: Oh, if nginx isn't running inside a container then you must connect to a published port.  You can also set the port to bind to the host's localhost interface `ports: ['127.0.0.1:8001:8000']` which will help here.

Comment: do `ports: ['127.0.0.1:8081:8000']` instead of `ports: -"8081:8000"` solve my problem, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running the nginx proxy outside of Docker, you must connect to the published `ports:` from your containers.

By default when you publish `ports:` they're published on all interfaces of the host system.  However, you can specify an alternate bind address.  If you set a backend service to only publish on the 127.0.0.1 localhost interface, it won't be reachable from off host.

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
    api:
        image: username/backendimgage:latest
        ports:
            - "127.0.0.1:8081:8000"
            #  ^^^^^^^^^
```

(If you're trying to connect from one container to another by using its host port – something like `http://host.docker.internal:8081` on MacOS/Windows platforms – this will interfere with that, but you should be able to use Docker-native inter-container communication there.)